# Asynchronous data reading

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am currently developing an application in WinForm C# to display cyclically values from a device.
Here is a short example:

```
public partial class MainForn : Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;

    public MainForn()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadDeviceData();
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(ReadDeviceData());
    }

    private int ReadDeviceData()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(300);//Simulation of long treatment for reading
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return rnd.Next();            
    }

}
```

In this example, UI is freezing during the 300ms of ReadDeviceData().
What is the best way to make ReadDeviceData() asynchronous, knowing that this method will be executed endless?

Thank you.

Complementary informations:
This communication is done with a CNC Fanuc which deliver an API which is a DLL:
Example inside ReadDeviceData() there is, in my soft, the following method to read variables:

```
FWLIBAPI short WINAPI cnc_wrmacror2(unsigned short FlibHndl, unsigned long s_no, unsigned long *num, double *data);
```

FlibHndl   [ in ] 
Specify the library handle. See "Library handle" for details.

s_no   [ in ] 
Specify the start custom macro variable number.

num   [ in/out ] 
Specify pointer to the number of custom macro variable.
The number which was written actually is returned.

data   [ in ] 
Pointer to the data of custom macro variable.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer:
as I understood OP has control over the `ReadDeviceData`, since `make` and not `call`.

and

This is certainly not the "best" way, but as from the comments, its my best effort with the amount of info provided. If you have no control over the method  `ReadDeviceData`, then `Task.Run` can be an option.  But it leaves you with the timer `tick` issue... you might want semaphores or concurrent queues... in all means not the best solution either.

---

The best solution, IMO, would be to create a service class. Call your hardware async in a loop and drop the data in a variable or buffer.

Then, in you UI part: read this value based on an event or timer etc; and use it to update the UI.

It will give you some benefits; for one, your service could also do other stuff, like: flush the data to a database, independent of the UI.

Do note; depending on your data from the device this can be tricky. Its basically how a web cam works, and it's often a hurdle to get the buffer reading/writing correctly if you're implementing that yourself.

---

*original post*:

This should do the trick:

```cs
//random is seeded based on current time; so best to do it once
Random rnd = new Random();

//the has the extra async keyword
private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //await this call because you need its data
    var data = await ReadDeviceData();
    //set the data; note: use the variable here
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(data);
}

//signature changed
private async Task<int> ReadDeviceData()
{
    //await a Task.Delay. (Thread.Sleep is thread blocking)
    await Task.Delay(300);//Simulation of long treatment for reading        
    return rnd.Next();            
}
```

---

So this is with the aid of your simulation.
If you are actually contacting the hardware; hopefully it has an API which has some Task based methods. If so; its easy, if not: you'll need to convert it yourself, which is tricky.

In that case we need more info on the device API.

Comment: Since the original post contains `int ReadDeviceData()`, IMO it's better to answer the original post, rather than assuming the library provides `Task<int> ReadDeviceData()`.

Comment: Awating on a `Timer.Tick` event will have *interesting* results.

Comment: Since the question is; `What is the best way to make ReadDeviceData() asynchronous ... ?` I assume OP has control over this part of the code and `ReadDeviceData` is not part of the devices API. Unless I misunderstood.

Comment: var data = await Task.Run(()=>ReadDeviceData()); should do the trick

Comment: @Jimi: yes, please elaborate. If you mean applying the `async void event handler hack`; it seems to be valid in this case. But I agree, an alternative Timer is most likely more suited. Can you recommend one?

Comment: It's not about the `async void` stuff, it's about a Timer ticking... You may need to enqueue the requests in a proxy method and dequeue in the Threadpool. ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem may be useful here. The aforementioned proxy method that handles a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` may also do. The question is not as simple as it may look like. Nobody said that the `ReadDeviceData()` method is awaitable, anyway.

Comment: @FrancescCastells: yes, but that would be a last resort effort. It is hardware, to there might be some actual asynchronous alternative.

Comment: @Jimi: going that road: a thread might also be an alternative; since its a never ending loop anyhow. The timer seems artificial. This would dismiss the concurrency issue. Updating the label would be a different cookie then XD

Comment: You can also run a Task and loop `await Task.Delay()` with the same interval of the Timer, for that matter. Then, do what, `BeginInvoke()` the Main thread? What is this method supposed to return and what is the OP doing with the results? Difficult to suggest something actually working without a minimal knowledge of the processing involved. Awaiting in a  `Timer.Tick` event is not exactly a solution, IMO. Do the Ticks overlap?

Comment: Hmm, now I read the question better; it's certainly not the `best` way. Ideally I would not use a timer in the form for data collection and use the async implementation of the device, but regarding to that; there are a lot of details missing.